# Showing certain elements from list when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I would like my button to display questions in my list of objects **in order** and **based on their status** (only show questions with status 0). If the question is showed, the status will change to 1 and in the next round it will not be showed again. I would like to keep on going until all the objects in my list have a status of 1.

I have managed to get a semi-working version. The only problem is that it doesn't skip the objects with status 1, it just doesn't display them when I click the button. I would like the "click" to skip everything until it finds a status of 0 and then display that. Hope that makes sense.

Current code:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button")
var textDisplay = document.querySelector("div")
var index = 0;

var questions = [{
    letter: "a",
    answer: ["aaaa"],
    status: 0,
    question: ["question 1"]
  },
  {
    letter: "b",
    answer: ["bbbb"],
    status: 0,
    question: ["question 2"]
  },
  {
    letter: "c",
    answer: ["cccc"],
    status: 0,
    question: ["question 3"]
  },
  {
    letter: "d",
    answer: ["dddd"],
    status: 1,
    question: ["question 4"]
  },
  {
    letter: "e",
    answer: ["eeee"],
    status: 0,
    question: ["question 5"]
  },
  {
    letter: "f",
    answer: ["ffff"],
    status: 1,
    question: ["question 6"]
  }
]

function nextQuestion() {
  if (questions[index].status === 0) {
    textDisplay.innerHTML = questions[index].question[1];
    questions[index].status = 1
    index = index + 1;
    index = index % questions.length;
  } else {
    index = index + 1;
    index = index % questions.length;
  }
}


button.addEventListener("click", function() {

  nextQuestion();
})
```

```html
<button type="button">Whatup</button>
<div>
  text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop to iterate through all the questions to check which is the next one to show.  Something like this:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var skip = document.getElementById("skip");
var textDisplay = document.querySelector("div")
var index = -1;

var questions = [
    { letter: "a", answer: ["aaaa"], status: 0,  question: ["question 1"] 
},
    { letter: "b", answer: ["bbbb"], status: 0,  question: ["question 2"] 
},
    { letter: "c", answer: ["cccc"],status: 0, question: ["question 3"] },
    { letter: "d", answer: ["dddd"], status: 1, question: ["question 4"] 
},
    { letter: "e", answer: ["eeee"], status: 0, question: ["question 5"] 
},
    { letter: "f", answer: ["ffff"], status: 1, question: ["question 6"] }
]

function nextQuestion() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      if (questions[i].status===0) {        
        textDisplay.innerHTML = questions[i].question;
        questions[i].status=1   
        index = i;
        break;
      }    
    }
}

function skipQuestion() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      index++;
      if (index > 5) {
        index = 0;
      }
      if (questions[index].status===0) {        
        textDisplay.innerHTML = questions[index].question;        
        break;
      }    
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nextQuestion();
});

skip.addEventListener("click", function() {
  skipQuestion();
});
```

```html
<button type="button">Whatup</button>
<button id = "skip">Skip</button>
<div>
    text
</div>
```

Comment: Hey buddy thanks for the reply this works perfectly! I had tried this loop previously without the break and it didn't work because it skipped straight to the last iteration. Do you mind explaining what the break does?

Comment: It gets you out of the loop.

Comment: What if I don't want to make the status = 1 every time I see a question? I would like to be able to see a question and skip it (keep status at 0) and then in the next round come back to that question I skipped.

Comment: Just remove this line `questions[i].status=1`

Comment: I tried that but then it gets stuck on the first question that has status=0! I think because it keeps on looping through till it finds a status = 0, but it’s always the same one...

Comment: In that case you need a different function.  Do you have different buttons?  One for skip and one for answering?

Comment: Yeah I have that exact setup, 2 different buttons. What would be the second function?